# Flot.js & JQuery.Ajax: Create graph from key-value-pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a graph in mvc using flot.js. The graph will be a line graph with 3 lines on it. I have created a set of 3 list keyvaluepair with date/value to be plotted on the graph as shown in the code below. Currently i get :  JavaScript runtime error: 'listvoltage' is undefined

Here's what I tried already:

Index.cshtml:

```
@if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.BatteryInfo)
                {

                    var listvoltage = new List<KeyValuePair<double, int>>();
                    var listtemperature = new List<KeyValuePair<double, int>>();
                    var listlevel = new List<KeyValuePair<double, int>>();



                    listvoltage.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, int>(
                        TMTMonitorAndCompare_Helpers.DateTimeHelpers.DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(item.TEST_DATE), Convert.ToInt32(item.battery_voltage)));

                    listtemperature.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, int>(
                        TMTMonitorAndCompare_Helpers.DateTimeHelpers.DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(item.TEST_DATE), Convert.ToInt32(item.battery_temperature)));

                    listlevel.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, int>(
                        TMTMonitorAndCompare_Helpers.DateTimeHelpers.DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(item.TEST_DATE), Convert.ToInt32(item.battery_level)));
```

CustomGraphinScript.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $.plot($("#placeholder"), listvoltage, { yaxis: { max: 1000 } });
});
```

Could anyone tell me what I need to do to the above to display this data on graph? is ajax required?

Comment: Can you provide your complete script?  Scoping of the listvoltage var is important and may be the problem, but it's not possible to be certain from the fragment above.

Answer (score 0):

Razor file is executing on the server side.  flot.js is executing on client/browser and they dont share the same type system. Thats why 'listvoltage' is undefined.

Put this in your razorfile.  Lookout for Date conversion between .NET and Javascript.  flot.js need Javascript timestamp.

```
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization

<script>
@{
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(listvoltage);
}
var timeserie = @Html.Raw(json);
</script>
```

Consider a Web API solution with JSON result and Ajax call.

Comment: Hi Anders thanks for the response, I see why listvoltage is undefined now. I tried placing your code in but due to the above code being within a table body listvoltage is still out of context, regards to the date conversion they are already in js timestamps. (using the custom helper above) any suggestions?

Comment: I see only a subset of your razor file, it is hard to see whats going on, but I should set the logic of the listvoltage in the Controller class. Easier to debug.